# change the radius of arc in ShapeDrawable in android

Tags: android, android-shapedrawable

I am creating an app which shows the angle of tilt of device and with that, the arc sweep shows the angle subtended. I am able to create the arc using ShapeDrawable, but not able to change the radius of this arc.

[image]

Below is the code i used:

```
circularArc = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(-90, angleValue));
circularArc.getPaint().setColor(Color.GRAY);
circularArc.setIntrinsicHeight(100);
circularArc.setIntrinsicWidth(100);
compass_image.setBackground(circularArc);
```

The setIntrinsicWidth and Height seem redundant here as it doesn't change the radius of the arc. Please suggest something so that instead of arc which is covering full image, I can have it over like half image.

Edit: tried Inset drawable as suggested by @pskink and i amusing code:

```
circularArc = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(-90, angleValue));
            circularArc.getPaint().setColor(Color.GRAY);
            InsetDrawable insetDrawable = new InsetDrawable(circularArc, 50,100,200,300);

            compass_image.setBackground(insetDrawable);
```

[image]

As you can see, it just moves the whole image. what I want is to move the circular arc to half as in the below image:

[image]

Comment: use `InsetDrawable`  as a "parent" `Drawable` (or `ScaleDrawable` but you would play with its `level` attribute a bit)

Comment: hi i didn't get this. can you please elaborate on this? i mean where is this InsertDrawable? sorry m little new on this, so not sure of this

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/InsetDrawable

Comment: @pskink please this doesn't work. I have mentioned in the edits

Comment: new InsetDrawable(circularArc, 100)

Comment: tried this, same issue with this as well

Comment: it just moves the whole image not just the arc

Comment: Yes i did ..  new InsetDrawable(circularArc, 100); 
, its the same result

Comment: no those points just move the image relative to initial position, so that doesn't work

Comment: I cannot test just now but first try four zeros, then try to change any param and see what happens, it should work - your child shape drawable should be deflated

Comment: yeah i mean i tested, then commented.. so it just moves the whole image as i have shown in above image, just the more integer higher value i give, more away from its original position it moves

Comment: FrameLayout main = new FrameLayout(this);
FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
fl.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(300, 300));
fl.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
main.addView(fl);

View v = new View(this);
ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(-45, -90));
shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.YELLOW);

InsetDrawable insetDrawable = new InsetDrawable(shapeDrawable, 30, 30, 30, 30);

// use either insetDrawable or shapeDrawable
v.setBackground(insetDrawable);
//v.setBackground(shapeDrawable);

fl.addView(v);

setContentView(main);

Comment: in above code you can either use `v.setBackground(shapeDrawable)` or `v.setBackground(insetDrawable)` - check the both - as i said `InsetDrawable` should work just fine

Comment: the base idea about `InsetDrawable` in the above code is that it adds 30 pixel insets (paddings) on every side (left, top, right and bottom) so the child drawable (`shapeDrawable`) is smaller by 60 pixels in width and height

Comment: Yeah when i checked, it was moving the whole image ..its night here, so going for sleep.. will check the code tomorrow and let you know .. i guess something i am missing not in shape drawable, but the way i am drawing image ..

Comment: but if you need it to be "dynamic" and want to show some `14°` in the center then instead of workarounds like `InsetDrawable` and `ArcShape` create a custom `Drawable` class and override its `draw(Canvas canvas)` method